# A question about a proof for why $\|x\|:=\inf\{\lambda>0\mid\frac{x}{\lambda}\in B\}$ is a norm

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I started studying functional analysis, a claim that was thought is
the second lecture claims that:

> Let $X$ be a vector space, $B\subseteq X$ is convex, symmetric around
>   $0$ and s.t
>   $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}nB=X,\quad\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}B=\{0\}$$ then
>   $$\|x\|:=\inf\{\lambda>0\mid\frac{x}{\lambda}\in B\}$$ is a norm on $X$,
>   moreover, the unit ball satisfy $\overline{B}=B_{1}$

I started reading the proof, which seems to claim that the set 
$$
I_x := \{\lambda>0\mid\frac{x}{\lambda}\in B\}
$$

is an interval of the form $(\alpha,\infty)$ or $[\alpha,\infty)$.

The proof uses this, and beforehand claim that $$\lambda\in I_{x},\mu>\lambda\implies\mu\in I_{x}$$

I think that this have something to do with the convexity of $B$,
but I don't know how to use it in order to understand why the above
implication is correct.

Can someone please explain it ?

**ADDED:** It seems that this is the case where $X=0$, but I still don't understand the claim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda \in I_x$, that means $\lambda^{-1}x \in B$. Then, by the convexity, for all $t \in [0,1]$, we have

$$(1-t)\cdot 0 + t\cdot (\lambda^{-1}x) = t\lambda^{-1}x \in B.$$

Choosing $t = \frac{\lambda}{\mu}$ shows $\mu^{-1}x \in B$ for $\mu > \lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both convexity and symmetricity around 0. Suppose $\frac{x}{\lambda} \in B$ and $\mu > \lambda$. $B$ is symmetric around zero, so $-\frac{x}{\lambda} \in B$. Since $\mu > \lambda > 0$, we have $0 < \frac{1}{\mu} < \frac{1}{\lambda}$. Therefore $\frac{x}{\mu}$ is in the "segment" $(-\frac{x}{\lambda}, \frac{x}{\lambda})$, and since $B$ is convex, $\frac{x}{\mu} \in B$ (you can make that precise).

Comment: You need the symmetry only for $\lVert -x\rVert = \lVert x\rVert$, not for the fact that $I_x$ is of the form $(a,\infty)$ or $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Your solution assumes that $0 \in B$, which is a consequence of symmetry + convexity.

Comment: That would also provide it, but $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty nB = X$ and $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n B = \{0\}$ both also imply $0 \in B$. You get a gauge ($p(x) \geqslant 0$, $p(tx) = tp(x), t \geqslant 0$, $p(x+y) \leqslant p(x)+p(y)$) from every convex absorbing set. That gauge is a seminorm if and only the set is balanced. That gauge has trivial kernel if and only if the set contains no ray emanating from $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Oh right I missed that. My apologies.